# R function to check if a vector is a subset of another

Tags: r, subset

I need to check if values_saved_dice is a subset from x, for example

```
values_saved_dice <- c(2,2,2)
x <- c(6,3,2,2,5)
```

I tried the following function, expecting it should return FALSE.

```
all(is.element(value_saved_dices, x)
```

But it returns TRUE, when apparently it should be FALSE - because the number "2" appeared 3 times in value_saved_dices and x only has "2" twice.

Would appreciate any help, thanks!

Comment: are you looking for count of adjacent elements i.e. `grepl(paste(values_saved_dice, collapse = ""), paste(x, collapse = ""))`

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what Im looking for! Was thinking of checking if the length of value_saved_dices does equal to the count of unique value from x, very appreciated !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We may `paste` the vector into string and use `grepl` to check if the substring is found or not

```
grepl(paste(values_saved_dice, collapse = ""), paste(x, collapse = ""))
[1] FALSE
```

Answer (score 1):

You could create a function:

```
cont = function(x, y) {
  z = x[x %in% setdiff(x, y)]
  length(z) == length(x) - length(y)
}
```

**Output:**

```
> values_saved_dice <- c(2,2,2) # triple 2
> x <- c(6,3,2,2,5)
> cont(x, values_saved_dice)
[1] FALSE
> values_saved_dice <- c(2,2)  # double 2
> x <- c(6,3,2,2,5)
> cont(x, values_saved_dice)
[1] TRUE
```